# Paint a multi-digit number with diferent colors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell ("A1") which can have a number (ex. 154639875) or a string (ex. overflow) and the objective is to paint it with 3 different colors in groups of 3 algarisms/characters. The code works with a string, but when I use an integer it uses only one color.

To try to fix it I use a cast of the number to a string and paste it in ("A2").

```
Sub MixColors()

    If IsNumeric(Range("A1")) Then
        Dim num As Long
        Dim word As String

        num = Range("A1").value
        word = CStr(num)
        Range("A2").value = word

        Range("A2").Characters(1, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
        Range("A2").Characters(4, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
        Range("A2").Characters(7, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen
        'MsgBox "Integer"

    Else
        Range("A1").Characters(1, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
        Range("A1").Characters(4, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
        Range("A1").Characters(7, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen
        'MsgBox "Not Integer"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: As soon as you put it into `A2`, Excel interprets it as a number again. Just add a `'` to the start of the value so it's interpreted as text.

Comment: Or change the number format to text before writing the value... beat me @Comintern ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number format needs to be text `"@"`:

```
Sub MixColors()
    If IsNumeric(Range("A1")) Then
        Range("A2").NumberFormat = "@"
        Range("A2").Formula = CStr(Range("A1").Value)
        Range("A2").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font.Color = vbBlue
        Range("A2").Characters(Start:=4, Length:=3).Font.Color = vbRed
        Range("A2").Characters(Start:=7, Length:=3).Font.Color = vbGreen
        'MsgBox "Integer"
    Else
        Range("A1").Characters(1, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
        Range("A1").Characters(4, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
        Range("A1").Characters(7, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen
        'MsgBox "Not Integer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was a simple question but it was my first time using this.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1) If you format the cells as **Text**, it will work properly with numbers or text.

2) Change to:

```
word = "'" & CStr(num)
```

which forces it to a text field.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was a simple question but it was my first time using this. Best Regards.